# Why does this merge no line up the columns in the Child File

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

Parent file looks like 1:A, 2:B, 3:C, 4:D, 5:E
Child file looks like 1:A, 2:B

I am trying to get the code to look at the "Child" file, figure out what the last row is, then move any line after that from the parent file to the child file..

It is selecting from the parent correctly, but shifts the data over in pasted the last column

**Expected Outcome**

Col1,Col2: [1,A] [2,B] [3,C] [4,D] [5,E]

**Current Outcome**

Col1,Col2,Col3: [1,A] [2,B] [&,3,C] [&,4,D] [&,5,E]

(I Dont know, I can't get this to properly display a table)

```
import pandas as pd

rpt = pd.read_excel("parent.xlsx",header=1) # Report log File
inv = pd.read_excel("child.xlsx", header=1) # invoice Log File

#gets the last row in the report files
inv_index = inv.index
inv_numb_row = len(inv_index)

#Gets last row in invoice log
rpt_last = rpt.iloc[inv_numb_row:]

#Merges files together
merge = [inv,rpt_last]
result = pd.concat(merge)
#print(inv_last)
print(result)

#outputs new file
result.to_excel("child.xlsx", header=False)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the missing header, best I can tell.  The concat seems to be looking for the header to match the rows on.  Since the header was ignored on the read, the two starting values are being used as the header for matching.  If the headers in the parent and child files are the same, then the code below works.  Hope that helps a little.  I changed the read_excel lines and the concat line (to tell the concat which join to use).

```
import pandas as pd

rpt=pd.read_excel("parent.xlsx",header=0) # Report log File
inv=pd.read_excel("child.xlsx",header=0) # invoice Log File

#gets the last row in the report files
inv_index=inv.index
inv_numb_row=len(inv_index)

#Gets last row in invoice log
rpt_last=rpt.iloc[inv_numb_row:]

#Merges files together
merge=[inv,rpt_last]
result=pd.concat([inv,rpt_last],join="inner")

#outputs new file
result.to_excel("child.xlsx")
```